# Luigi does not send error codes to concourse ci

Tags: concourse, luigi

I have a test pipeline on concourse with one job that runs a set of luigi tasks. My problem is: failures in the luigi tasks do not rise up to the concourse job. In other words, if a luigi task fails, concourse will not register that failure and states that the concourse job completed successfully. I will first post the code I am running, then the solutions I have tried.

luigi-tasks.py

```
class Pipeline1(luigi.WrapperTask):
    def requires(self):
        yield Task1()
        yield Task2()
        yield Task3()
```

tasks.py

```
class Task1(luigi.Task):
    def requires(self):
        return None

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget('stuff/task1.csv')

    def run(self):
        #uncomment line below to generate task failure
        #assert(True==False)
        print('task 1 complete...')
        t = pd.DataFrame()
        with self.output().open('w') as outtie:
            outtie.write('complete')

# Tasks 2 and 3 are duplicates of this, but with 1s replaced with 2s or 3s.
```

config file

```
[retcode]
# codes are in increasing level of severity (for most applications)
already_running=10
missing_data=20
not_run=25
task_failed=30
scheduling_error=35
unhandled_exception=40
```

begin.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
export PYTHONPATH='.' 
luigi --module luigi-tasks Pipeline1 --local-scheduler
echo $?
```

pipeline.yml

```
# <resources, resource types, and docker image build job defined here>

#job of interest
- name: run-docker-image
  plan:
  - get: timer
    trigger: true
  - get: docker-image-ecr
    passed: [build-docker-image]
  - get: run-git
  - task: run-script
    image: docker-image-ecr
    config:
      inputs:
      - name: run-git
      platform: linux
      run:
        dir: ./run-git
        path: /bin/bash 
        args: ["begin.sh"]
```

I've introduced errors in a few ways: assertions/raising an exception (ValueError) within an individual task's run() method and within the wrapper, and sys.exit(luigi.retcodes.retcode().unhandled_exception). I also tried failing all tasks. I did this in case the error needed to be generated in a specific manner/location. Though they all produced a failed task, none of them produced an error in the concourse server.

At first, I thought concourse just gives a success if it can run the file or command tasked to it. I'm not sure it's that simple, though. Interestingly, when I run the pipeline on my local computer (`luigi --modules luigi-tasks Pipeline1 --local-scheduler`) I get an appropriate return code (e.g. 30), but when I run the pipeline within the concourse server, I get a return code of 0 after the luigi tasks complete (from `echo $?` in the bash script).

Would appreciate any insight into this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suspicion is that `luigi` doesn't see your config file with return codes. Its default behavior is to return `0`, whether tasks fail or succeed.

This experiment should help to debug that:

1. Force a failed job: add an `exit 1` at the end of `begin.sh`
2. Hijack the job: `fly -t <target> i -j <pipeline>/<job>` -> select `run-script`
3. `cd ./run-git; /bin/bash begin.sh`
4. Ensure the luigi config is present and [named appropriately](https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuration.html), e.g. `luigi.cfg`
5. Re-run the command: `LUIGI_CONFIG_PATH=luigi.cfg bash ./begin.sh`
6. Check output: `echo $?`

Comment: thanks! It was a matter of the config file being inappropriately named (mine had a typo). Changing to ```luigi.cfg``` corrected my issue.